# LAravel 5.4: Response from controller to blade by Ajax (laravel, json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I want to response the data from controller to AJAX as array, but it keep showing this error:

> json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given

the following is my code:

```
 function get_show(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $leads = Lead::find($id);

        $leads_attendances = DB::table('event_attendances')
            ->leftJoin('leads', 'leads.id', '=', 'event_attendances.lead_id')
            ->leftJoin('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'event_attendances.group_id')
            ->select('groups.name as event_name', 'leads.name as name', 'leads.company_name', 'event_attendances.attend as attend_status')
            ->where('event_attendances.lead_id', '=', $id)
            ->get()->toArray();

        $output = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'country' => $leads->country,
            'company_name' => $leads->company_name,
            'lead_stage' => $leads->lead_stage
        );

        echo json_encode($output,$leads_attendances);
    }
```

This is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('main.get_show')}}",
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        console.log(response);
                        $('#model2').modal('show');

                        document.getElementById('leads').innerHTML += response.output.company_name;
                        document.getElementById('leads').innerHTML += response.leads_attendances;
```

New error:

> leads:7515 Uncaught ReferenceError: leads_attendances is not defined
>       at Object.success (leads:7515)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at z (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

Output response of incpect:

> {"output":{"id":"25","country":"","company_name":"comp1","lead_stage":"under"},"leads_attendances":[{"event_name":"event1","name":"LEMUN","company_name":"comp1","attend_status":"Yes"},{"event_name":"event2","name":"ZDMJ","company_name":"comp1","attend_status":"Yes"},{"event_name":"event3","name":"MNAl","company_name":"comp1","attend_status":"Yes"},{"event_name":"event","name":"Khalai","company_name":"comp1","attend_status":"Yes"},{"event_name":"event4
>   ","name":"Zamel","company_name":"comp1","attend_status":"Yes"}]}

Build table in JS:

```
success: function (response) {


                        console.log(response);
                        $('#myModaleee').modal('show');


                        var leads_attendances=response.leads_attendances;
                        document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += '<table>';

                        for(var i=0;i<leads_attendances.length;i++){
                            var event_name=leads_attendances[i].event_name;
                            var name=leads_attendances[i].name;
                            var company_name= leads_attendances[i].company_name;
                            var attend_status= leads_attendances[i].attend_status;
                            document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+event_name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+company_name+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+attend_status+'</td>'
                                +'</tr>';
                        }
                        document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += '</table>';


                    }
```

The first array ($output) passed and working well with Ajax, but the second collection showing that error. I still need to pass more than these collection, any help how to pass it and make it work with Ajax?

Thank you

Comment: You should post the `$output` you're getting

Comment: And as like the error said, the parameter 2 to `json_encode` should be in integer which is  `option ` not an array like you passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller return Json Response like below :

> return response()->json($response,200);

```
function get_show(Request $request)
{
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $leads = Lead::find($id);

        $leads_attendances = DB::table('event_attendances')
            ->leftJoin('leads', 'leads.id', '=', 'event_attendances.lead_id')
            ->leftJoin('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'event_attendances.group_id')
            ->select('groups.name as event_name', 'leads.name as name', 'leads.company_name', 'event_attendances.attend as attend_status')
            ->where('event_attendances.lead_id', '=', $id)
            ->get()->toArray();

        $output = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'country' => $leads->country,
            'company_name' => $leads->company_name,
            'lead_stage' => $leads->lead_stage
        );

        $response=array('output'=>$output,'leads_attendances'=>$leads_attendances);
        return response()->json($response,200);
}
```

suppose you have table div :

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th> event_name </th>
        <th> name </th>
        <th> company_name </th>
        <th> attend_status </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

your ajax function should be :

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/url here',
   method:'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(response){
     console.log(response);
     var id = response.output.id;
     var country= response.output.country;
     var company_name=response.output.company_name;
     var lead_stage =response.output.lead_stage;
     var leads_attendances=response.leads_attendances;
     var trHTML="";
     for(var i=0;i<leads_attendances.length;i++){
        var event_name=leads_attendances[i].event_name;
        var name=leads_attendances[i].name;
        var company_name= leads_attendances[i].company_name;
        var attend_status= leads_attendances[i].attend_status;
        let trRow="<tr>"+
                  "<td>"+event_name+"</td>"+
                  "<td>"+name+"</td>"+
                  "<td>"+company_name+"</td>"+
                  "<td>"+attend_status+"</td>"
                  +"</tr>";
       trHTML=trHTML+trRow;
     }
     $('#tbody').empty();
     $('#tbody').append(trHTML);

   },
   error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
});
```

Comment: How to get the response data in AJAX ?

Comment: Sorry, last one not working `var leads_attendances=response.leads_attendances;` 
show me `[object][object]` , how to solve it and go further each element in this eloquent in for loop ?

Comment: @AbdallaWasef , var leads_attendances , showing you `[object][object]` means it is  array and you have to for loop it

Comment: `console.log(leads_attendances)` . <-- see what it display

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: leads_attendances is not defined

Comment: @AbdallaWasef , please add your response you are getting in console  to question , so i can understand what you r getting in output

Comment: @AbdallaWasef , please right click > InspectElement , go to Network tab , check response of your ajax request , what r you getting there , paste that in quesiton

Comment: It show 1 column for $output array which is correct, but the $event_attendances have many records, it show only one record. why ?

Comment: @AbdallaWasef , can you add screenshot of NetworkTab / resposne

Comment: I tried before but couldn't, keep showing me ignore

Comment: any suggestion to print array of object ?

Comment: for loop through it

Comment: please post the array which you are geting in response , so i can loop thrugh it

Comment: ok, done ,, I added it to question, please check it ,, Thanks

Comment: @AbdallaWasef , r you want display this in list or table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189650/discussion-between-abdalla-wasef-and-saurabh-mistry).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your way but don't know why not printed anything, I tried another way shown in the updated question, but this way shows the data but now show the table border <tr> or <td> is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use like that `echo json_encode($output,$leads_attendances);`

Try this

```
$data = ['output' => $output, 'leads_attendances' => $leads_attendances];

return response()->json(['results'=> $data]);
or
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, it working and passed the data I think, but when I print the variables show me undefined. This is how i Print the data: 

`success: function (data) {
 document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += data.leads_attendances; // This one for full array not working 

 document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += data.country; // element in array not working too
 document.getElementById('lead_details').innerHTML += data.company_name; // element in array not working too
`

May I know how to get the passed data, Is it by `output['company_name']; ` ??

Comment: print your json response using `console.log(response)` you will get idea or post here

Comment: yes, `response.leads_attendances;` show me `[object][object]`, how to solve it and go further each element in this eloquent in for loop ?